# Add fields to Object Mongoose way

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to push a field into Object "options" to my Database dynamically. I use Mongoose v. 4.13.11.

My schema

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Model', 
{
   ...
   options: Object   
});
```

My backend in NodeJs - not working but in console log I have the desirable result:

```
controller.addingModels = (req, res) => {

    Model.findById(req.body._id).exec((err, model) => {
         model.options[req.body.name] = req.body.myvalue;
         model.set({
             options : model.options
         });
         console.log(model.options);
         model.save();
    });

};
```

The output of console log is:

```
{ Maria : 25, John : 20, Perry : 31 }
```

but it didn't update in my database.
The strange thing here when I am adding manually the value (see below) it works and the database do the update and recognized as an object:

```
         model.set({
             options : { Maria : 25, John : 20, Perry : 31 }
         });
```

What can I do in order to work dynamically? If you need some more informations please don't hesitate to ask me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `$set` operator. Setting `{new: true}` returns the modified document.

```
    model.options = {your new values} 

    Model.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id,{$set: {options : model.options}}, {new: true}, function(err, updatedDocument){
    console.log(updatedDocument);         
    model.save();
    });
```

Comment: I don't want to use [] I need to be an object. I am already know how to do in array but is not my purpose in that example.

Comment: So options will always only contain one object?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

Try defining Schema like this,
Consider I want to add dynamic fields to the meta object. I can do this like this.

```
  var blogSchema = new Schema({
    title:  String,
    meta: {}
  });
blogsSchema.find(req.body._id).exec((err, blogData) => {
     blogData[0].meta[req.body.name] = req.body.myvalue;
     console.log(blogData[0].meta);
     blogData[0].save();
});
```

Comment: I changed the schema to options : {} then I did what you say and it throws an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Comment: module.exports = mongoose.model('Model', 
{
   ...
   options: {}  
});
controller.addingModels = (req, res) => {

    Model.findById(req.body._id).exec((err, model) => {
         model[0].options[req.body.name] = req.body.myvalue;
         
         console.log(model[0].options);
        // model.save();
    });

};

Comment: use **find** instead of findbyid.